# How to concatinate string ang a num in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, concatenation, meanjs

I have values like this

```
var npi = {
            code1: 'sm1',
            code2: 'sm8',
            code3: 'sm9',
            code4: ''
          }
```

I want to push first 3 items into an array

```
var arr = [];
for (var i =0;i< 3;i++) {
  arr.push(npi.code+''+i);
}
```

It says error npi.code is undefined since it is not considering npi.code1 instead npi.code.

Here i think its concat problem.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: There is no `npi.code0` Your `i` starts from `0`

Comment: Use `npi['code'+i]`

Comment: Consider using `Object.keys`.

Comment: Any reason why only the first 3? Could it be you only want the none empty onces?

Answer (score 3):

`npi.code+''+i` won't work because there is no such key `code+''+i` . Instead you could access the key in this way `npi['code'+i]` (like accessing array using index).

Also in your code, the `i` start with `0` and `code0` is undefined. So, `i` should start with `1`

Try this one

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1;i <= 3;i++) {
  arr.push(npi['code'+i]);
}
```

Comment: Would need to start at 1, also good idea to explain what is happening + maybe explain Object.keys?

Comment: I just edited the code for work true. Owner of question should edit for himself..

Comment: @SagarV It is true that he also could explain why the square brackets should be used, however then the answer from Durga should be updated/downvoted as well

Comment: @Icepickle Durga's answer -> donwvoted -> he edited it -> upvoted

Comment: @SagarV True :) I also upvoted both answers ;) Nice that you were so consistent

Answer (score 2):

```js
var npi = {
            code1: 'sm1',
            code2: 'sm8',
            code3: 'sm9',
            code4: ''
          }

var arr = [];
for (var i =1;i<= 3;i++) {
  arr.push(npi['code'+i]);
}
console.log(arr)
```

For your case Iterate from 1 to 3, and get value from obj like `npi['code'+i]`, here you need to use bracket as [Property_accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), because it takes value as string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [***Object.keys()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method and a `forEach()` loop:

```js
var npi = {
  code1: 'sm1',
  code2: 'sm8',
  code3: 'sm9',
  code4: ''
}
var arr = [];

Object.keys(npi).forEach(function(key) {
    if(npi[key] != ''){
      arr.push(npi[key]);
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

> The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

The reason why your code is not working, is because when trying to get the values of an object using `.` notation, the property can't be a string(when you concatenate using `+''+` you practically convert the **object property** into a string). String works only in case of `[]`. For example:

```js
arr.push(npi.code + '' + i); //returns undefined
arr.push(npi['code' + i]); //returns your value
```

Comment: @SagarV, oh, ok, you're right. Corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, you didn't, you only excluded possible empty values (which was not the question)

Comment: I retracted the vote. But FYI you should break it when it complete 3 iterations.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but where is the logic?! I think that what the OP is intending, is to push **non-empty** elements into the new array. The original `array` may contain multiple elements, not just 4. I think my example applies on more levels and is more dynamic. You can give as many downvotes as you want, but I think this is the better answer.

Comment: My only reason for having the downvote is rather that you didn't explain why the . notation with concatination is not working. I agree with the non empty ones, but for that I asked it in a comment

Comment: _You can give as many downvotes as you want,_ I already retracted the downvote and the new down votes is not me. I down vote for a cause and I will be very happy in retracting it. in your case, I am neutral. Since OP said he want first 3, you could better ask for clarification to OP whether it is first 3 or non empty.

Comment: @Icepickle, that's because when trying to access objects values like that (using the `.`) you can't use strings. It works with string only when using `[]`

Comment: @SagarV, oh, ok. Sorry for that. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you would like to append to the object key, you should use npi['code' + i] instead of npi.code+i. Because npi.code+i means appending the value of (i) to the value of the key (code) in npi, which doesn't exist.

Second of all, you should loop starting from i = 1 instead of i = 0. So that the loop starts with npi['code1'] not npi['code0'] which also doesn't exist.

Also, the loop condition should be i < 4 instead of i < 3 so that the loop ends after i = 3 instead of i = 2

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
    arr.push(npi['code' + i]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var arr = [];
for (var i =0;i< 3;i++) {
  arr.push(npi['code'+i]);
}
```